# Schematic Numbering Scheme

Tags: schematics

I need help determining what are some helpful bits of information to include in a new schematic number scheme. For example:

Schematic ID

Revision (Major, Minor, Fix)

etc.

Its not critical, but I would like to define some good info to include in the numbering system before I commit to it for this new project.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've consulted for several medical device companies.  They have a common theme in revision numbering.

- Revisions for released documents were letters: `A` then `B` then `C` etc.
- Revisions for unreleased R&D versions were numbers: `01` then `02` then `03` etc.
  Then eventually the package would get released and become `A`.

That way, it was easy to tell released documents from unreleased ones.

I was also asked to maintain a revision history for schematics.  It was a table on the title sheet of the schematic.  It had 4 columns: rev number, summary of changes, who, when.

[update in response to the comment by @DerStrom8]
Good point.  I do the `PRELIMINARY` stamp too.  The color is carefully chosen to be eye-catching, but not alarming.

[image]

Comment: At work I use 01, 02, 03, etc on all documents (released and unreleased) but all unreleased documents have a "PRELIMINARY" stamp above the title block in the bottom right corner. When the documents are released this stamp is removed. That way it is easy to tell if it's still in development if it has the "PRELIMINARY" stamp on it.

Comment: @DerStrom8  Good point.  I do the `PRELIMINARY` stamp too.